# How to remove the gap between two navigation bar items?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

There is a small gap between the two items in navigation bar.
This is the html, css code:

```css
    body{
            margin: 0px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        ul{
            padding: 15px 0px;
            background: grey;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        li{
            display: inline;
        }
        a{
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 15px 15px;
        }
        a:hover{
            background: grey;
            color: black;
        }
        a:active{
            background: white;
        }
```

```html
 
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
```

[image: Note the gap between the items]

This is the output.

The gap is reduced if I set the `margin` of `a` tag to `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `display: table;` to you `<ul>` element. This will remove the space.

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul{
    display: table;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    background: grey;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
}
a{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}
a:hover{
    background: grey;
    color: black;
}
a:active{
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, the spacing is because of `display:inline`. Check [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more information about the spacing

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  background: grey;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

a:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: black;
}

a:active {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Support</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you have to set the margin of every element to 0:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
 }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  background: grey;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

a:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: black;
}

a:active {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Support</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this to your css:

```
a {
  margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Output:

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the whitespace. There are a number of techniques you can use to fix the issue.

1. Remove the space between the closing and opening `li` tags:

   ```
   <ul>
     <li>
     <a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
     <a href="#">Support</a></li><li>
     <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Remove the closing `li` tag:

   ```
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a>
     <li><a href="#">Support</a>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
   </ul>
   ```
3. Use comments to remove the space:

   ```
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
     --><li><a href="#">Support</a></li><!--
     --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
4. Use `font-size:0` for the `ul` element in the CSS:

   ```
   ul { font-size: 0; }
   li { font-size: 16px; }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Add a space to hide the spaces...

```css
        body{
            margin: 0px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        ul{
            padding: 15px 0px;
            background: grey;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        li{
            display: inline;
        }
        a{
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 15px 15px;
        }
        a:hover{
            background: grey;
            color: black;
        }
        a:active{
            background: white;
        }

        /* Add this */
        li:after {
          content: ' ';
          font-size: 0;
        }
```

```html
 
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing space and redefining border definitions.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  background: grey;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
}

li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: black;
}

a:active {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```